# signalr : after Authentication i get error 400 (Bad Request) in client-side

Tags: .net-core, signalr, bearer-token

after Task.CompletedTask i get error 400 (Bad Request) in "client-side"
What am I missing to go through the Authentication phase?

Server:

```
  public class Startup : StartupBase
{

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = options.DefaultScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = options.DefaultScheme;
        })
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
               {
                   OnMessageReceived = context =>
                   {
                       var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                       var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                       {
                           context.Token = accessToken.ToString().Substring("Token ".Length).Trim();

                       }
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   }
               };
           });
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddSingleton<IMongoDBService, MongoDBService>();
    }


    public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder, IEndpointRouteBuilder routes, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        builder.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        builder.UseAuthentication();
        builder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {       
            endpoints.MapHub<PrintEventsHub>("/Events/PrintEventsHub"); 
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationEventsHub>("/Events/NotificationEventsHub");
        });
    }
}
```

Hub:

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class NotificationEventsHub : Hub//, IPrinterEventsHub
{
    
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly ITelegramServices _telegramServices;
    private readonly ISaveEventToDBServices _saveEventToDBServices;
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationEventsHub> _Context;

    private string ConnectionID;

    public NotificationEventsHub(IHubContext<NotificationEventsHub> context,
                    ISession session,
                    ITelegramServices telegramServices,
                    ISaveEventToDBServices saveEventToDBServices)
    {
        _Context = context;
        _session = session;
        _telegramServices = telegramServices;
        _saveEventToDBServices = saveEventToDBServices;
    }
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        ConnectionID = this.Context.ConnectionId;
        var connectedUser = Context.User.Identity;

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
    public async Task GetNotificationMsg(string jsonStringNotification)
    {

    }


}
```

Client:

```
    public static async Task<bool> SendPrinterEventToCloudManager()
    {
        var SignalRConnectionInfo = new SignalRConnectionInfo();

        SignalRConnectionInfo.AccessToken = "test";

        string _SignalRUrl =
```

"https://localhost:44300/Events/NotificationEventsHub";

```
        try
        {
            HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_SignalRUrl,
                o => o.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(SignalRConnectionInfo.AccessToken)).Build();


            await connection.StartAsync();

            await connection.InvokeAsync("GetNotificationMsg", "testmsg"); 

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i am try to use JwtBearer token and after i read the value what's next step to aprrove that the user Authentication?

Comment: I experience the same issue as of today. When I put an [Authorize] attribute on a Hub it fails to authenticate. It has worked before.